# Adding a backslash to a dynamic char array

Tags: c, dynamic

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *arr;

    arr = (char*)malloc((strlen(argv[1]) + 1) * sizeof(char));//1 additional byte for the backslash.
    strcpy(arr, argv[1]);
    strcat(arr, '\\');

    return 0;
}
```

After this code I get `Access violation reading` error.
Basically I'm just trying to append a backslash to a dynamic string that contains the first argument of the program.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you don't need the first backslash, since you are working with a char and not a char *.

Comment: @FernandoKarpinski If I leave only one backslash so cancel the apostrophe.

Comment: Hum, I guess I was wrong. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably wrong:

```
arr = (char*)malloc((strlen(argv[1]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

`argv[1]+1` is the second argument, if exists. You wanted:

```
arr = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 2);
```

I simplified this line a lot since `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition and adding `2` instead of `1` as you would need additional byte for the nul terminator. Casting `malloc` is [unnecessary](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html).

`strcat` operates on strings. `'\\'` is not a string. It should be:

```
strcat(arr, "\\");
```